# How to calculate center coordinate of rectangle

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems

How to calculate center of rectangle? Info available is rectangle's width and length and bottom left corner coordinate and angle theta between x-axis and the line from bottom left corner to bottom right corner.

ie: bottom left corner coordinate is (100,900), width is 800, height is 600, theta is 1 degree. What is the center coordinate?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsuqc.png)

method I tried is

1. find the other 3 corner coordinates assuming the rectangle is aligned to x-axis
2. calculate the center coordinate of the axis aligned rectangle
3. rotate the center coordinate back by angle theta using the bottom left corner as origin.

This however doesn't seem to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: That should work.  If you provided your math/code for doing so, we could probably help you find your mistake better.

Comment: You can find opposite corner then average the points, this will be the centre. Please provide your formulas.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph Camacho and PC1, it was a coding error that was giving me the wrong result. The method does work.